# How to find TAB in string using %SCAN in RPGLE

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

How can I use %SCAN built-in function to find first 'TAB' in string ?

I ever read function documentation : https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r1/ic2924/books/c0925083586.htm

Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean by 'TAB'?  AFAIK, the EBCDIC character set does not defined a TAB character.

Comment: I don't know how to say it in english.
Hex code = 09

Comment: hex 09 is tab in ASCII, not in EBCDIC.  Check out ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/globalization/gcoc/attachments/CP00037.pdf

Comment: I found a solution : %SCAN(X'09':myString)
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Find first tab in string.  The tab is hex05 in ebcidic

nonzero x is found.

```
eval x = %scan(x'05':mystring:1)
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key